# How can bind value in Web view in URL textbox in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am trying to auto bind value in page which is open by URL in UWp and I am using C#. This is part of my **C# Code**

```
public LayoutOnlineAccess()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
                    
        String sURL = "https://www.uptodate.com/login";
        try
        {
            if (NetworkAvailabilty.Instance.IsNetworkAvailable)
            {
                Uri webURL = new Uri(sURL);
                webView1.Navigate(webURL);
                webView1.Settings.IsJavaScriptEnabled = true;
            }
            else                
                CommonCls.ShowToastMessage("Internet Connection is not available.");                
        }
        catch (Exception){}
    }



 private async void ctlBrowser_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {                                         
            string functionUsernamee = string.Format("document.getElementById('userName').value = '123456789';");
            string functionUsername = string.Format(@"alert('TEST')");               
            await webView1.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { functionUsernamee });
            webView1.Stop();
}
          }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             //new ExceptionHelper().AddException(ex.Message, this.ToString(), "ctlBrowser_NavigationCompleted");
        }
    }
```

I tried  alert for check. ITs working or Not but not worked.
This is **XAML CODE**

```
<WebView x:Name="webView1"  Height="985" Width="1920"                 ScriptNotify="WebView1_ScriptNotify_1"  
                NavigationStarting="ctlBrowser_NavigationStarting" NavigationCompleted="ctlBrowser_NavigationCompleted" />
```

Thank You
Best Regards

Comment: I'm confused about what you want to get. Could you please tell me what is the target control for the binding and what is the source value for the binding?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT  By WebView we can open any URL in Our UWP Application. Same thing I am trying here I used web view and Open a page With URL And After open the Page I want to Fill the TextBox Value(Which presence in page) by Backend side.

Comment: So you want to assign a value (from your C# code) to the TextBox placed on the website, right?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT yes..

Answer (score 0):

I have to say you can't direct bind a value from your c# code behind to the website using data binding. You still need to manually assign the value to the website using [WebView.InvokeScriptAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescriptasync?view=winrt-22000#windows-ui-xaml-controls-webview-invokescriptasync(system-string-windows-foundation-collections-iiterable((system-string)))). When calling the `InvokeScriptAsync`, please make sure the JS method could run correctly.

Comment: Hey sir, Please review my code, already I used this.

Comment: @poonammishra I noticed that. So I say there is no data binding way to reach what you want and you still need to use the way you are using now. Just make sure the JS method is correct.